# ReferenceError: MatInputModule is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I tried to use `MatInputModule` in the `imports` of `@Ngmodule` I got this error

> ReferenceError: MatInputModule is not defined

My app.module.ts file looks like this:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
@NgModule({


declarations: [..],
imports: [...,
    MatDatepickerModule, 
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule    //<-----the error is generated when i add this 
  ],
  providers: [ ..., MatDatepickerModule],
```

The example.component.html is:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <label class="col-md-4">attended date</label>
  <input mdInput [matDatepicker]="mydatePicker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #mydatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The example.component.ts is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }
 ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I don't think that the question I stated above is a duplicate since I tried solving it using mdInput as well but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, I have added code snippets in my question above.

Comment: Try this - `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="mydatePicker">`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have already tried using `matInput`. But, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Where did you imported `MatInputModule`? Like `import { MatInputModule   
 } from '@angular/material'`

Comment: Or try: `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I added the code `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'; ` in app.module.ts and the error is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked!